# Erro ao utilizar variáveis em uma query

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia,
sou novo em PHP e estou tentando fazer um form que posta os dados em um bd mysql.

Código HTML (Bootstrap):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nome" class="col-md-1 control-label">Nome:</label>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Hubert Weber Xylo, 2012"></input>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="descricao" class="col-md-1 control-label">Descrição:</label>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <textarea name="descricao" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Código info.php:

```
<?php
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234");
  if (!$connect) {
    die('Connection Failed:' .mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("db_teste", $connect);

  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];

  $user_info = "INSERT INTO 'mytable' ( `NOME`, `DESCRICAO` ) VALUES ( $nome,  $descricao )";

  if (!mysql_query($user_info, $connect)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo 'Cadastro concluido.';
  mysql_close($connect);
```

Mas o erro que eu estou recebendo é o seguinte:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mytable' ( `NOME`, `DESCRICAO` ) VALUES ( TesteNome, TesteDesc )' at line 1

Oque eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Os valores `$nome` e `$descricao` devem estar entre aspas: `"INSERT INTO nome_tabela ( NOME, DESC ) VALUES ( '$nome',  '$descricao' )"`

Comment: Lembrando: é completamente inseguro realizar queries desta maneira no PHP. Leia mais sobre PDO: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php e/ou utilize um framework (Laravel 4/5 por exemplo, ou CodeIgniter caso ainda não tenha experiência com frameworks - posteriormente migre para o Laravel).

Comment: Agora o erro é:
    Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''vinho' ( `NOME`, `DESC` ' at line 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver! Coloquei a string toda do $user_info com aspas simples e os VALUES com aspas duplas. Funcionou!

Comment: Se possível coloque o código de como ficou.

Comment: Eu editei pro código certo :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.

Como já mencionados nos comentários, utilize PDO para uma maior segurança na execução das queries.

Sobre o erro, no seu caso utilize a seguinte querie:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (NOME, DESC) VALUES ("$nome", "$descricao");
```

Comment: Quando eu coloco a aspas duplas aparece isso:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$nome' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\db_teste\info.php on line 33

Comment: Hum.. uma coisa que eu vi ali era que eu estava usando uma palavra reservada, DESC. Mas eu já mudei para DESCRICAO no banco, e alterei o código. Mas o erro continua o mesmo

Answer (score 0):

tem que colocar as string entre aspas e escapar para nao dar erro no PHP

```
$user_info = "INSERT INTO 'mytable' ( `NOME`, `DESC` ) VALUES ( \"$nome\",  \"$descricao\" )";
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta colocar as variaveis dentro da query envolvidas em aspas simples.
algo tipo:

```
( '$nome',  '$descricao' )
```

Comigo funciona assim. Afinal, sua string usa aspas duplas.